# Ubuntu 14.04 Installation on Fujitsu Siemens Notebook - Operating System not found

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, system-installation, mbr

I had windows vista installed on my laptop and installed ubuntu 12.04 next to it, everything worked, then i installed ubuntu 13.10 and it worked. A few weeks ago i wanted to install 14.04 alone on the machine but it ended in

"Operating System not found"

I tried to fix it, followed many suggestions i could google, used boot-repair, tried to fix grub manually, but nothing helped. Finally i even exchanged my harddisk becuase i thought - maybe something is just broken.

Now i intalled a 120GB SSD, followed the default installation instructions again but the same problem. The installation completes successfully and after reboot

"Operating System not found"

Here my latest result from bootrepait:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8015123

I burned a installation DVD from Ubuntu 14.04.1 64 bit image
My Notebook is a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo Si 3655
Centrino / 64 bit / Intel Core2Duo P8400 2.26Ghz / 4GB Ram / installed 120GB SSD / Intel GMA450 graphics.

Comment: Update: I tried to install another ubuntu based distribution and chose linux mint >> same problem.

Comment: Update 2: Tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 and do dist-upgrades to 14.04 but still got the same error, then i booted from live cd again to fix mbr/grub but no success. Does anyone have an idea? I need to get my notebook working again. It seems Ubuntu 14.04 or GRUB2 damaged my MBR on 2 hard disks now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i managed to boot, here is what i did:
(i dont know what exactly solved the problem)

1. Install Ubuntu 14.04.01 with manual partitioning
2. create own partition for boot (ext4)
3. install and reboot -> still same error
4. insert boot-repair disk (not ubuntu live cd, the
   preconfigured ubuntu package with boot-repair)
5. repair mbr - with repair partitions checked
6. after the next reboot i got a slightly different error
7. boot again from boot repair disk and executed the
   recommended repair rebooted and finally grub showed up