# Operating System not Found

Tags: boot, 14.04, boot-repair

I've Xbuntu installed on a 128GB SSD that boots and runs without issue on my desktop. (Even on its own with all other drives disconnected) 
When placed in my laptop, although it sees the disk, I receive an "Operating System not Found" error during boot. I have tried the steps outlined in this similar post:

[Ubuntu 14.04 Installation on Fujitsu Siemens Notebook - Operating System not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509682/ubuntu-14-04-installation-on-fujitsu-siemens-)        notebook-operating-system-not-fou

Step 5 did not provide this option - only the default recommended repair which I did.

Below is the output of my boot-repair dump. I've run the repair but it has not been successful in resolving the issue. My Home partition is encrypted.There is / was no dual booting of any kind going on. Any suggestions very much appreciated, thanks.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10158465/

Comment: Do you use uefi on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

Your desktop system is an UEFI system and your laptop is not (as I can safely assume as it was running Vista), therefore the laptop does not know how to boot this UEFI HD.

You basically two options:

- buy an UEFI-compatible Laptop *of the same brand as the laptop* (otherwise the two systems will still not be compatible)
- <sub>Turn off UEFI</sub> **Warning**: this will mean that you have to re-install the Desktop completely with all it's OSes, applications and data.

**Why?** UEFI is not as **U**niversal as the name implies for us end-users as we would wish.  All vendors use this to *lock* in customers and take away your freedom, instead of giving you more. (Just like they did with he BIOS, which is different on all computers)

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue more than twice,

The reason why this is not working is, your laptop is not UEFI compatible.

**Solution 1**

This solution worked for me is as follows,

Try to make a bootable pendrive using dd command.

Example: `sudo dd if=input.iso of=/dev/sdc`

Replace input.iso with your Ubuntu iso file and also replace the destination location (USB drive). You can get the drive location from Disks application.

**solution 2**

1. Upgrade your hardware.
2. Try to install old version of Operating System (this will work).

I've spend days to fix this issues, I hope this helps.